# How to implement local image upload functionality in TinyMCE with Carrierwave (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, carrierwave, image-uploading

I'm building a blog app. The editor(TinyMCE) for creating the post content works fine and a simple image upload with carrierwave works as well. Now I want to add image upload functionality into TinyMCE. I have installed the tinymce-rails-imageupload gem which actually should make the implementation of image upload in TinyMCE easier.

application.html.erb

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ 
  selector:'textarea',
  plugins: "imageupload link lists media wordcount",
  menubar: false,
  toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic link | imageupload media"
  });
</script>
```

Unfortunately after I add "imageupload" on "plugins" and "toolbar" and then when I refresh the site I am getting this error:

[image]

**Is this a bug from the tinymce-rails-imageupload gem or is this an issue from the TinyMCE source?**

**How can I make this work?**

If you have any hints I would be very thankful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are loading TinyMCE from the Cloud any plugin that is not part of TinyMCE's download is considered "external" to the editor.

You will need to load that plugin using the `external_plugins` configuration option:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#external_plugins

Comment: Since Im using a gem it will be very hard to make this work... I guess it is easier to use TinyMCE not from the cloud! Thanks for taking me into the right direction! :)